# Adding 'netvet; to sausages

Tags: sausages

I'm not entirely sure what the word in is in the English language but where I'm from there is this one type of food 'skilpaadjies' which is lamb livers encased in the fat that surrounds the liver of the sheep.

I'm curious as to whether this type of fat can be used in general sausage making and also can you make a cured lamb liver sausage with 30 percent of this type of fat?

Also what should I know about cured lamb's sausages?

Comment: I don't know about fat around the liver, but there's 'caul fat', which is the fat from around the stomach.  It's almost like a net, so you can wrap things up in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netvet - or caul fat doesn't work well with sausages - it is hard fat - rather use soft fat for sausages. Like lamb's tail or something similar like pork fat.

I usually make skilpaadtjies from ground sheep's liver, that are spiced etc and then wrapped in netvet before being grilled on the braai.

Never tried cured lamb sausages - lamb has quite a pronounced taste and drying it will make it even more pronounced. We have used lamb in droe wors though - with beef and game meat.